# ORA-03297 on Oracle Tablespace alter

Tags: oracle

I have a database with 4500GB storage on AWS RDS. My "users" tablespace has 3749700 MB allocated. Out of which 1583777.63 MB is used and 2165922.38 MB is free.

When I do:

```
alter tablespace users resize 3500G;
```

It gives me:

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-03297: file contains used data beyond requested RESIZE value
03297. 00000 -  "file contains used data beyond requested RESIZE value"
*Cause:    Some portion of the file in the region to be trimmed is
           currently in use by a database object
*Action:   Drop or move segments containing extents in this region prior to
           resizing the file, or choose a resize value such that only free
           space is in the trimmed.

I have tried this - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.Oracle.CommonDBATasks.html#Appendix.Oracle.CommonDBATasks.CreatingTablespacesAndDatafiles
```

How can I fix my tablespace?

Answer (score 2):

You have segments allocated across the tablespace with "gaps" of free space. 
In order to reclaim it you should first reorg the tablespace. 
See: [reclaiming unused space](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/reclaiming-unused-space)
https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/reclaiming-unused-space
It's a rather long process for such a large file.... 
Btw, if you have EM installed it's just a couple of mouse clicks

Regards 
Jony

Comment: How to do it on EM?

Comment: Hi, not near a laptop so can't post images... But try Starting at the "tablespaces" screen, select the "<tablespace>" tablespace by clicking the radio group button next to it, select the "Reorganize" action and click the "Go" button.